# I'm coming up with erroneous results counting characters in string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to count the occurance of letters in a line. But my results are coming up way wrong. I'll just present the function I believe contains the error.

```
void readAndCount(int &numWords, int letterCount[])
{
    //set letterCount[] numwords initial values
    memset(letterCount, 0, 26);
    numWords = 1;

    char a = ' ';
    while(a != '\n')
    {
        a = getc(stdin);
        if (a == ' ' || a == ',' || a == '.' || '\n')
            ++numWords;
        else
            if(a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
            {
                ++letterCount[a - 'A'];
            } else if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z') {
                ++letterCount[a - 'a'];
            }
    }

    return;
}
```

this is a string yields:

```
3 words
1 a
4194305 g
1 h
3 i
4196355 k
32630 n
4197445 o
32630 r
4197379 s
2 t
4196576 w
32767 z
```

I've already tried fflush()ing stdin before reading input.
Any pointers would be appreciated, but please don't just write it for me.

Comment: Is it a typo? `|| '\n'`. Shouldn't it be `|| a == '\n'`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't see any C++ here.  Perhaps the C tag is more appropriate.

Comment: @Duck `int &numWords` is a reference parameter.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  I guess that counts then.

Comment: I get the same results with or without fflush(stdin);

Comment: Then you don't need `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: Your word count algorithm is bogus, by the way. You start at `1` increment the word count with given punctuation (even if the previous character was punctuation) and then increment it again at the end of the line. This means for a single word with a double trailing space, you're going to count 4 words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memset(letterCount, 0, 26)` zeroes out 26 *bytes* of memory pointed by `letterCount`, instead of 26 *ints* as you wanted. How about `memset(letterCount, 0, 26*sizeof(int))`?

Comment: But didn't quite fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), replace the call to [c](/questions/tagged/c)'s `memset()` with:

```
std::fill(letterCount, letterCount + 26, 0);
```

Or:

```
std::fill_n(letterCount, 26, 0);
```

...and this will fix the array initialisation. The arbitrary numbers that you're seeing after 'f' are whatever garbage was in RAM before your program was loaded.

Also, this:

```
if (a == ' ' || a == ',' || a == '.' || '\n')
```

Should be:

```
if (a == ' ' || a == ',' || a == '.' || a == '\n')
```

**Note:** In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), we prefer [**`std::cin.get(a);`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) over [c](/questions/tagged/c)'s `a = getc(stdin);` (but that would make no difference to how your code executes, just a matter of style).

Comment: You know, I just noticed the '\n' after posting, but fixing doesn't change output. Strange, huh?

Comment: Are you sure you've rebuilt your executable?